# Need help saving a list and then loading it later

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have this list:

```
SOME_LIST = []
```

And the data in it comes from user input as the program goes on.

So after the program is run it ends up like:

```
SOME_LIST = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```

How can I save `some_list` to a CSV file so that when the program is closed, the CSV file can be loaded when the program is run again and `some_list` would have all the elements in it again.

My attempt:

```
import csv
import os.path

def main():
    SOME_LIST = []
    for i in range(1 , 6):
        SOME_LIST.append(int(input('Enter an integer')))
    print ('Press 1 to save your list')
    print ('Press 2 to load your previous list')
    user_answer = int(input('Enter your selection now'))
    if user_answer == 1:
        saved_file = open('My destination folder')
        writer = csv.writer(saved_file, dialect='excel')
        writer.writerow(SOME_LIST)

    if user_answer == 2:
        '''However you can load the csv file and update some_list with \
           the files contents'''

main()
```

I just get a unicode error that says it can't read bytes in position 2-3

Attempt #2

```
def main():
    SOME_LIST = []
    for i in range(1 , 6):
        SOME_LIST.append(int(input('Enter an integer')))
    print ('Press 1 to save your list')
    print ('Press 2 to load your previous list')
    user_answer = int(input('Enter your selection now'))
    if user_answer == 1:
        saved_file = open('My destination folder')
        f.write((",".join(SOME_LIST))
        f.close

    if user_answer == 2:
        '''However you can load the csv file and update some_list with \
           the files contents'''

main()
```

Comment: Have you simply *tried doing that*? Python has a `csv` module you could look into, and various other options for serialising data to files.

Comment: You're looking for object persistence. Check out [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Yeah, I gave it a shot.  I'll update with what I tried.

Comment: And what happened? Give a [mcve], thus far you haven't mentioned *what the problem is*.

Comment: what is in the list?

Comment: In this example, just a bunch of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working version that can both save the list and load it:

```
def main():
SOME_LIST = []
for i in range(1 , 6):
    SOME_LIST.append(int(input('Enter an integer')))
print ('Press 1 to save your list')
print ('Press 2 to load your previous list')
user_answer = int(input('Enter your selection now'))
if user_answer == 1:
    f = open('2.txt','w')
    list=[str(i) for i in SOME_LIST]
    f.write((",".join(list)))
    f.close()

if user_answer == 2:
    f = open('2.txt','r')
    aux=f.read()
    list=aux.split(",")
    print (list)
    f.close()
```

main()

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to import the `csv` module? As far as I know a `csv` file is just a regular text file with values separated by commas, hence why

> "Comma Separated Values"

The fact that you only want to store a single list makes it useless to import a separate module for this.

The best option is to use the `join()` and `split()` methods of the string object.

How to save your file:

```
print(",".join(SOME_LIST))
```

The first string `","` is the separator and the argument is the list to be separated by commas.

How to load the file:

```
SOME_LIST=(file.read().split(",")
```

This will read the file with commas as it was written and it will separate it by commas, saving the result in the `SOME_LIST` variable.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to implement your post.  Thank you very much for it. I'll post my attempt at your method above.

Comment: Hi. I will post an implementation tomorow as I am now at a bar looking at the EURO 2016 Final and I won't be home at my dorm until tomorow probably.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as little as possible. Basically you need to open the file in write mode to write the csv file. Also you have to specify the extension (in this case you were writing to a csv so it will be .csv, but there are other options such as .txt). To read the file you can use the csv reader and I gave an example of how to do that. I put some comments in the code below too.

```
import csv
import os.path

def main():
    SOME_LIST = []
for i in range(1 , 6):
    SOME_LIST.append(int(input('Enter an integer')))
print ('Press 1 to save your list')
print ('Press 2 to load your previous list')
user_answer = int(input('Enter your selection now'))
if user_answer == 1:
    #Notice the w in the line below and the .csv, these both must be specified
    # if you want to write a csv file!
    saved_file = open('My destination folder.csv','w') 
    writer = csv.writer(saved_file, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(SOME_LIST)

if user_answer == 2:
    #Open the file, be sure to include the entire path to the file you wish
    # to open!
    file = open('path to my destination folder/My destination folder.csv','r')
    rd = csv.reader(file)
    l = list(rd)[0] #Note make sure to put this [0] at the end!
    l2 = []
    for j in range(5):
        num = l[j]
        l2.append(int(num))
    print(l2)
main()
```